# MATLAB Data Cursor Mode

Tags: matlab, datatip

I have a simple class that plots basic x and y data. Within the class I have a method that enables the data cursor mode, customizes the text, and collects and saves the points. I'd like to change the behavior of the method so that I can collect only two points at a time. Right now it stores every point even when I turn off the data cursor mode and turn it back on to use it. Here is my code for my class:

```
classdef CursorPoint


    properties
        Xdata
        Ydata
    end

    methods
        function me = CursorPoint(varargin)

            x_data = 0:.01:2*pi;
            y_data = cos(x_data);
            f= figure;
            plot(x_data,y_data);
            me.DCM(f);

        end

        function DCM(me,fig)
            dcm_obj = datacursormode(fig);

            set(dcm_obj,'UpdateFcn',@myupdatefcn)
            set(dcm_obj,'enable','on')
            myPoints=[];

            function txt = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj)
                % Customizes text of data tips

                pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
                myPoints(end + 1,:) = pos;
                txt = {['Time: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
                    ['Amplitude: ',num2str(pos(2))]};

            end

        end

    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you change the `myPoints` variable to two variables called `myPointCurrent` and `myPointPrevious`. When ever the `myupdatefcn` method is called you would move the contents of `myPointCurrent` into `myPointPrevious` and then store the current position in `myPointCurrent`.

The new function (with some error checking) would look something like:

```
function txt = myupdatefcn(empt,event_obj)
    % Customizes text of data tips
    myPointPrevious=myPointCurrent;

    pos = get(event_obj,'Position');
    myPointCurrent=pos;

    txt = {['Time: ',num2str(pos(1))],...
        ['Amplitude: ',num2str(pos(2))]};
end
```